# What is the difference between the concepts of mutual orthogonality and pairwise orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u,v,w\in\mathbb R^3.$ What is the difference between the concepts of mutual orthogonality and pairwise orthogonality of  $u,v,w\in\mathbb R^3?$

Comment: I believe they are the same thing.

Comment: ditto, agree with massy.